# Sap Crystal Report load fail

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Error : crystal report load fail(after long time of loading)

I developed c# app contain sap crystal report and it doesn't work on another machine ..
Single tip I installed sap crystal report runtime 32bit

Tools I used in development :
.netframework 4
Crystal report runtime 64bit
Sql server 2014

Thank you I hope you will help me !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest add your report ro your current working project if you are using vs 2010 :
[image]

Some errors comes up load report failed:
First: check report path.
Secode: crystal report need to log in into your database working.